# Undefined response in XHR.complete on Android 2.x

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, undefined, response, zepto

I have a simple webpage, that uses AJAX requests and results returned by [XMLHttpRequest.response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) event. This is the code:

```
$.ajax
({
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    url : serverUrl,
    data : {request: 'check'},
    complete: function(xhr, status)
    {
        var failed = true;

        if(status === 'success')
        {
            alert(typeof(xhr.response));
```

Last line echoes `undefined` on Android 2.x. On Android 4.x it is (as expected) `string`.

I tested it on LG GT540 with Android 2.3.3 and GSmart Rola G1317D with Android 2.2.2. Non of these devices has mobile Chrome installed (if that matters) and I'm using internal, system-level browser.

I'm using `Zepto`, if that matters, but I heard that its `.ajax` definition is quite the same as in `jQuery`.

Tests on Samsung Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.3 and Sony Xperia E with Android 4.1.1 are successful. `XMLHttpRequest.response` type is `string` and website continues to work as expected.

Can someone confirm, that this is really undefined under Android 2.x? If yes -- what is correct approach of getting server response in `complete` event? Is it possible in this case (undefined `xhr.response`) or do I have to return to old, good `success` / `error` events for Android 2.x?

Comment: Try Using responseText instead of just response. Let me know if it worked for you. `xhr.responseText`

Comment: You have answered my quite old question (actually, I forgot about it! :]). But even so, your suggestion sounds interesting. Feel free to reformulate it as full-featured answer, so I can accept it and bring you some reps, if you wish.